# Why angular2 form works incorrectly with html <form> element?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angular

I've noticed some strange behavior of `<form>` element in ng2 and I need someone to explain me it :)

I have created simply Plunker example 
https://plnkr.co/edit/vdrHJBNdd26y6YhPXTHD?p=preview

So now it is working fine. If you enter some value and click "Add parameter", input value will be updated in model and saved into input field.

But if you wrap your `<div>`with `<form>` element like this https://plnkr.co/edit/vdrHJBNdd26y6YhPXTHD?p=preview
and input smth into a field and click again "Add parameter", form will be refreshed and your value will disappear (in model it still exists). Can't figure out why it happens. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I don't know why the form submits, but I'm not sure you can construct dynamic forms the way you did. In your Plunker, for instance, all your input and select fields have the same "name" attribute, which doesn't seem correct. Have you looked at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html?

Comment: @AngularFrance yeah, maybe you are right and I'm not doing it well. But I wanted to try template-driven approach with ngModel and two data binding.

Comment: @AngularFrance the problem was with `name` attribute repeating multiple times, so the newly added value is replacing all previously added field to default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is when `form` renders `all` its input with via help of `ngFor`, we display all the fields. But the problem is we're having same name attribute for all element which is `name="name"` & `name="test"`. So when new input gets added with `name` value `''` & `type` `this.types[0]`(`String`) it applies the same value for all form element.

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let param of paramsList; let i=index">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="param.name" name="{{'name'+i}}">
      <select [(ngModel)]="param.type" name="{{'type'+i}}">
          <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type">{{type}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Yc5LeKyFY8UYdrpe8ltt?p=preview)

> **Note:** Somehow `[attr.name]="'name'+i"` isn't working.

Comment: @ilyablbnv `formGroup`(model-driven-form) would be better way to go for such scenario.. though glad to help you, Thanks ;)